# Azure logic Apps large file support

Tags: azure-logic-apps

The video update from the Azure Logic Apps team suggested that large file (exceeding the 100MB limit) support is due for release back in August 2017.

https://youtu.be/DSPNHLOVu_A?t=1514

But I haven't seen it mentioned in the documentation for the connectors.

How do I know which connectors support large files? And how do I make use of it, I'd guess it's different to the normal having the payload in the body of a message (as that's limited to 100MB).

EDIT:

I struggled to find the release notes at first, but saw they are actually in the azure portal now rather than on a blog (which is quite cool).

Here's a deep link: https://ema.hosting.portal.azure.net/ema/1.30101.1.594429775.180105-1338/Html/iframereleasenotes.html?locale=en&trustedAuthority=https://portal.azure.com

I couldn't see it mentioned.

Also this user voice ticket hasn't been closed yet:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/17229566-increase-ftp-connector-limit-above-50mb

Either it's not been documented as released / difficult to find or perhaps although mentioned in the video it didn't get released in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by this video.

https://youtu.be/qBD_RswoaPg?t=631

It sounds like it's shipped for blob storage -> ftp connector and combinations thereof.

But it didn't mention the http connector (which I'd need to copy the file down prior).

It's not mentioned in the release notes as far as I could tell.

Interestingly however in the settings of the http connector there is this:

[image]

But the address didn't lead to a page discussing chunking and enabling it doesn't allow me to exceed the 100mb limit.

---

EDIT
Discussing in the MSDN forums, there's a suggestion that the http connector not working for files above 100MB could be a bug: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/741529c7-a5ad-44e0-8839-497fe8548dee/chunked-transfer-for-http-action-not-working?forum=azurelogicapps